# Prisma ORM: How to search with the findMany modelQuery and operator "contains" in an encrypted database?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, orm, prisma

I am creating software with backend in NodeJS, database in **MySQL** and **Prisma ORM**. In my software I have a table with **encrypted patient data**. There is a screen for administrators in the software. The administrator must perform realtime patient searches as they type in an input field. For example, he has to search for patients by their surname. How can I do a search in the **surname column encrypted** using the modelQuery findMany and with the **"contains" operator**?

Comment: Seems pretty related to your last question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747208/how-can-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-prisma

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at this [discussion](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23908/how-to-search-a-mysql-database-with-encrypted-fields)

Generally you shouldn't be encrypting data stored in a database that you need to search over, so you might want to revisit your use case and use some other solutions.

From Prisma Perspective, you would need to decrypt the data first in order to use contains clause, which might not be the best fit.

Comment: In the end I was able to find a solution to my problem! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73747208/how-can-i-encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-prisma